# Distinct query in SQL script which is nested

Tags: sql-server, subquery, unique, distinct

I have all data is in one single table and when an entry is inserted, it appends a unique ID for that account. I then have a script which performs several calculations across all entries. However what I want to do is script only distinct entries in the script so I can perform the same calculation but just on the first one it finds for that account, as the info does not change between entries. The script looks as follows

However when I try to nest a sub query, it asks for a group by or aggregate, however I don't want to group by these unique account codes, otherwise I will get 1000's of rows. I just want to aggregate all entries but perform a distinct on the account details. For example age is in every entry and therefore I just need to use 1 entry for the account and not all 10 that are in there, as I will get duplicates.

```
select
count ([Accountid]) as Total, 
round (AVG ([AGE]),2) as AVGAGE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN [AGE] BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-4],
SUM(CASE WHEN [AGE] > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Over 100]
from [dbo].[table1]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question completely, I suppose that you want something like that;

```
select
count ([Accountid]) as Total, 
round (AVG ([AGE]),2) as AVGAGE, 
SUM(CASE WHEN [AGE] BETWEEN 0 AND 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [0-4],
SUM(CASE WHEN [AGE] > 100 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Over 100]
from [dbo].[table1] where Accountid NOT IN (select Accountid from [table1] group by Accountid having count(*) > 1)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi @rainman sorry that did not work... That brought back the same results. You cant do max on the on the accountID, as that is a unique ID. So really it needs to be a distinct on the accountID.

Comment: basically the data is formatted in a way that the Account ID will be "ABC123", so ABC123 will be shown say 3 times. But what I need to do is only use 1 of ABC123 and average the age for ABC123 and not take it 3 times and use it to average. So really I need to distinct the accountIDs and then use the info found to use for the calculations.

Comment: Okey, I guess I got your question now. I updated my answer.

Comment: will this only bring back unique distinct entries? As it appears to be just recounting. Also what is the final statement records? As it does not like that in my sql script.

Comment: I couldn't understand actually what do you want ? Provide an example please. I calculate average for duplicated records and i retrieved them as one record.

Comment: HI, No I want to ignore duplicate records and just count single entries in to a banding and also complete an average calculation